# R - count similar values in pair-wise comparing groups in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, intersection

I have observational data for basketball players. Each ID represents a player.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "c"),
                  V1 = c(1, 3, 2),
                  V2 = c(1, 2, 2),
                  V3 = c(3, 1, NA))
df
  id V1 V2 V3
1  A  1  1  3
2  B  3  2  1
3  c  2  2 NA
```

I want to pair-wise compare all players and count the number of similarities among their variables.

It doesn't matter if the values are found in different columns. Note that some players have `NA` in some fields.

The desired outcome should look something like this:

```
desired <- data.frame(id_x = c("A", "A", "B"),
                      id_y = c("B", "C", "C"),
                      similar = c(2, 0, 1))
desired
  id_x id_y similar
1    A    B       2
2    A    C       0
3    B    C       1
```

The real data consists of tens of thousands of players, so performance is important too.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can also use [`proxy`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=proxy) for this problem:

```
library(proxy)

df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "c"),
                 V1 = c(1, 3, 2),
                 V2 = c(1, 2, 2),
                 V3 = c(3, 1, NA))

myfun <- function(x, y) {
  sum(unique(setdiff(x, NA)) %in% y)
}

pr_DB$set_entry(FUN=myfun, names="myfun", distance=FALSE, loop=TRUE)

similar <- proxy::simil(df[, -1L], method="myfun")

res <- combn(df$id, 2L)
res <- data.frame(id_x=res[2L,], id_y=res[1L,])
res$similar <- as.integer(similar)

print(res)
  id_x id_y similar
1    B    A       2
2    c    A       0
3    c    B       1
```

It does seem somewhat faster on my machine:

```
df <- data.frame(id = sample(10e2),
                 V1 = sample(1:15, 10e2, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(2:16, 10e2, replace = TRUE),
                 V3 = sample(3:17, 10e2, replace = TRUE))

system.time({
  similar <- proxy::simil(df[, -1L], method="myfun")

  res <- combn(df$id, 2L)
  res <- data.frame(id_x=res[2L,], id_y=res[1L,])
  res$similar <- as.integer(similar)
})

   user  system elapsed 
   7.84    0.05    7.92
```

Answer (score 1):

Will give two different approaches:

```
 A=lapply(apply(df[-1],1,list),unlist)
 combn(A,2,function(x)sum(unique(na.omit(x[[1]]))%in%unique(na.omit(x[[2]]))))
  [1] 2 0 1
```

or

```
 B=apply(df[-1],1,function(x)apply(df[-1],1,function(y)sum(unique(na.omit(x))%in%unique(na.omit(y)))))
 B[lower.tri(B)]
 [1] 2 0 1
```

Comment: this code also counts the NA values. Is there a way to ignore these?

Comment: Use `na.omit` within the `x`

Answer (score 1):

We can make a list of each pair of rows and use that to find the intersect of them. Look below:

```
toCheck <- combn(rownames(df), 2, simplify = FALSE)
names(toCheck) <-
  sapply(toCheck, paste, collapse = "&") 

sapply(toCheck, function(x){
  length(base::intersect(as.list(df[x[1],-1]), as.list(df[x[2],-1])))
})

# 1&2 1&3 2&3 
#   2   0   1
```

**Testing on your larger dataset:**

```
set.seed(45)
df2 <- data.frame(ID = sample(10e2),
                  V1 = sample(1:15, 10e2, replace = TRUE),
                  V2 = sample(1:16, 10e2, replace = TRUE),
                  V3 = sample(1:17, 10e2, replace = TRUE)) 

M_M_approach <- function(mdf) {
  Check <- combn(rownames(mdf), 2, simplify = FALSE)
  names(Check) <-  sapply(Check, paste, collapse = "&")

  sapply(Check, function(x){
    length(base::intersect(as.list(mdf[x[1],-1]), as.list(mdf[x[2],-1]))) })
}

M_M_approach(df2)
# 1&2 1&3 2&3 
#   1   1   2 

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(M_M_approach = M_M_approach(df2), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  M_M_approach 225.6985 228.1924 248.5623 250.4814 255.1007 283.3385     5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm benchmarking the great answers provided by Onyambu.

Make a larger test-sample:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = sample(10e2),
                 V1 = sample(1:15, 10e2, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(2:16, 10e2, replace = TRUE),
                 V3 = sample(3:17, 10e2, replace = TRUE))
```

Run benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
bench <- microbenchmark(

# option A
A=lapply(apply(df2[-1],1,list),unlist),
A1=combn(A,2,function(x)sum(unique(x[[1]])%in%unique(x[[2]]))),

# option B
B=apply(my.df2[-1],1,function(x)apply(df2[-1],1,function(y)sum(unique(x)%in%uni
  que(y)))),
B2= B[lower.tri(B)],

# repeat 5 times
times=5)
```

Produces:

```
bench

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
A     10.44847    10.83849    11.79438    11.33756    11.34568    15.00171     5 a  
A1 25420.53573 25735.88333 26721.22973 25802.89428 26658.98114 29987.85417     5  b 
B  52173.85540 52519.34839 53327.35931 52661.64372 54508.70321 54773.24582     5   c
B2    33.43663    34.16278    34.91674    35.19001    35.81182    35.98246     5 a
```

The original data is larger.

Are there options with greater performance?